# Disable multiple-account sign in Gmail

Tags: gmail, google-multi-login

I accidently linked two accounts together with Gmail multiple account sign-in.

When I go to https://www.google.com/settings/security there is supposed to be an option about multiple sign in under the password there, but it is not. The (old) Google help FAQ page for how to do this now 404's.

Comment: Please don't cross post - http://superuser.com/questions/431105/disable-multiple-account-sign-in-gmail?noredirect=1

Answer (score 2):

Just Sign-out of both the Google Accounts. It is as simple as that.

Comment: So then this feature simply allows you to authenticate for many accounts but only in the one session? Once that session has ended then you can't auto-authenticate (switch)?

Answer (score 1):

At the bottom of the [help page for multiple sign-in](http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1721977&ctx=cb&src=cb&cbid=-1130kws371dia&cbrank=5) they suggest signing out of all your accounts and signing into the one you use.

They used to allow you to enable/disable multiple sign-in, but it looks like that ability is gone now.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem, too: I logged into my Gmail from my sister's Gmail without logging her out first (oops) and it linked our accounts. So, just hit sign out on **any** of the accounts, and it will make you re-log in to all of them. Then just don't re-log in with the account you wanted removed (or log everyone else out first by logging just one Gmail account out; it logs all Gmail accounts out simultaneously) and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

**To de-link the two accounts all you need to do is sign out.** This will signout of **all** accounts you have logged in. Then just sign back in with your preferred account.

At present there is no feature to specify a particular account to sign out of. It’s either all or nothing I’m afraid.

Answer (score 0):

The way you do it is in the right corner drop down where you would go to switch between accounts, click on "add account" (as if you were going to add a third). At the bottom of your list of accounts to the left it says "add account" and the right it says "edit". Select "edit" and all you have to do it "x" out the one you want to remove.